# Merge deactivated and new account

Tags: support

In my last company I have my company-domain email account by which I have created Stack Overflow account and when I left the company my account has been deactivated. 
Can I merge my old Stack Overflow account with other Stack Overflow account?.

Update: Now I can only login with one account so can not authenticate other one if that required any authentication :(

Comment: Use this contact form: http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Answer (score 8):

You need to [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), select the option for merge, and fill in all of the details that you can. If we need more information from you to verify your ownership of both accounts, we'll ask. It sounds like you know all of the non-public stuff about both of them, so it should be a pretty routine request.